# findOne returns undefined on the server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

Here is my code on the server:

```
Meteor.publish('currentRequest', function (requestId) {
        console.log('from publish');
        console.log(requestId) // The id is printed successfully
        console.log(Requests.findOne({_id: requestId})) // returns undefined
        return Requests.findOne({_id: requestId});
    });
```

The item ID is printed but `.findOne()` doesn't seem to work as it returns `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code looks fine but, as `findOne` does not return a Mongo cursor, your publish won't work. You will need to use the `find` function.

Comment: @GaëtanRouziès find() returns empty array. Like if there is no document with that _id but it exists

Comment: Where did you check the existence of your document ? Where do you get this "id" ? Check manually the content of `Requests.find().fetch()`, i'm pretty sure you wont find your document because your query is correct and the document doesn't exist.

Comment: @GaëtanRouziès Requests.find().fetch() returns all the elements in the collection. The "_id" looks like this, { _id: { _str: '598d74ebc048c71100e8f730' }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question will be: because there is no document satisfying your search query.

According to [documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-findOne):

> Finds the first document that matches the selector, as ordered by sort and skip options. Returns `undefined` if no matching document is found.
>
> Equivalent to `find(selector, options).fetch()[0]` with `options.limit = 1`.

Also, as it has been pointed by @GaëtanRouziès, this publication won't work, because `.findOne` returns document/`undefined` instead of cursor.

Comment: "find()" returns empty array. It doesn't find the document in the database

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi Well, it seems that you don't have documents in the collection at all. And don't forget that `.find()` returns cursor. You should call `.fetch()` on this cursor to obtain found documents.

Comment: Requests.find().fetch() returns all the elements in the collection. The "_id" looks like this, { _id: { _str: '598d74ebc048c71100e8f730' }

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi Then it should be clear how you should find your documents there. `{ '_id._str': requestId }`

Comment: I tried it, it returns an object but doesn't look as expected. below is part of what it returns, should I edit the question and post it all? "{ _mongo: 
I20170917-20:21:29.312(4)?    { _observeMultiplexers: {},
I20170917-20:21:29.312(4)?      _onFailoverHook: { nextCallbackId: 0, callbacks: {}, bindEnvironment: true },
I20170917-20:21:29.312(4)?      db: 
I20170917-20:21:29.312(4)?       { domain: null,
I20170917-20:21:29.312(4)?         _events: {},
"

Comment: I think it would be better to ask another question, because your current one has been answered already.

Answer (score -1):

.findOne() return the response in asynchronus way. you need to pass a callback function to findOne and use return statement in callback function. Please take a look at the sample code below.

```
CollectionName.findOne({
     query : query
   }, function(err, resp) {
   if (err) {
     throw err;
   } else {
     return resp;
   }
});
```

Comment: You're wrong, in `Meteor` calling DB is synchronous.