# Why my Async and Await still not do the job of sequence execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, async-await

I'm a newbie to Node.js and not sure if I understood Async/Await correctly. Here's what I'm trying to do

I'm passing values to a function and I'm expecting it to work like

Step 1. add both values
 Step 2. Fetch a document from db based on value from step 1
 Step 3. return the document fetched from step 2.

But the result I see is

Step 1. add both values 
Step 2. return undefined while db query is running
step 3. finish running query

How do I achieve desired output from this.

```
var someFunction = async (a,b)=>{
  var k;
  try{
    k = a+b; 
  }catch(err){
    return(err);
  }

  var document;
  try{
    document = await db.collection(somecollection).findOne({_id:k})
  }catch(err){
    return(err);
  }
  return(document);
}

someFunction(4,5).then((result)=>{
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Which database are you using?  Are you sure that `db.collection(somecollection).findOne({_id:k})` returns a promise?

Answer (score 1):

`findone` may return undefined if no match found 
[findOne returns undefined on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263532/findone-returns-undefined-on-the-server)

In the first `try...catch` block, why do you worry about an exception of adding two variables? that never result on error in javascript.

Also make sure you're passing the _id correctly to findone, Mongo uses UUID to calculate `_id` and I don't think that can be returned from adding a + b

Comment: This is an example I've taken here in real the first try will have much more to do. in the second block document exists but takes time to run the query, if I print the document in second block it prints moments later undefined is printed which shows that return statement is executed before the second block is finished executing.

Comment: try to cast k to ObjectId, add `var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId` in top and then `await db.collection(somecollection).findOne({_id: new ObjectId(k) })`